# How to position an element a little more to the top

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am trying to place the second file upload button exactly next to the first one below the second rectangle but apparently top, padding-top (bottom) and margin-bottom (top) does not seem to work properly! Please help me out!

```
    .file1 {
      padding-left: 340px;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .file2 {
      margin-left: 1010px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

[image: the output (the second button appears a little down)]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a negative margin like: `margin-top: -8px;`

Comment: that worked! i tried it various times but now it seems to work out of nowhere lmao...thanks though